# calling msdb.sp_send_dbmail via pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, t-sql, pyodbc

I am attempting to call a sproc that wraps T-SQL's sp_send_dbmail procedure. It simply creates the query, and then passes that and a hardcoded subject and recipient to the Microsoft supplied sproc. When running from sql management studio, the sproc executes as expected and I receive an email. From pyodbc, it doesn't send an email. The contents of my sproc look similar to:

```
declare @qry varchar(MAX)
set @qry = 'select * from table'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail    
@recipients = 'email@email.com',
@subject = 'my email',
@query = @qry

select * from table
where 1=0
```

I have also tried toggling the @exclude_query_output, flag but that had no effect. I am invoking that sproc via the following method:

```
def execute_sproc(query, cnxn):
    cursor = cnxn.cursor();
    rows = cursor.execute(query)           
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=columns)
```

where the query is simply executing my wrapper sproc. As I mentioned before, the wrapper sproc works when run from the management studio, but no email is sent when called here. I am using the same credentials to access my database in both places. I have also used this function to successfully call other sprocs, but none of them have contained exec statements, nor have they done many of the other things that im sure sp_send_dbmail is doing.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks,
Max Goldman

Comment: Just a thought - make sure the sql server profile is setup correctly.    Add the @profile='myprofile' to your call for sp_send_dbmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think this comes down to a misunderstanding of either the sendmail sproc, pyodbc, or both. I have another method for calling sprocs that edit the database:

```
def execute_commit_sproc(query, cnxn):
cursor = cnxn.cursor();
cursor.execute(query)           
cnxn.commit()
```

The only difference being that the former expected a result set, whereas the latter makes changes to the db, and uses pyodbc's commit mechanism to save the results. I did not realize the sp_send_dbmail required this to be called in order for the email to be sent. I am still unsure of why (what is getting written to, what pyodbc::commit() is doing under the hood, etc.)

Comment: Max, I find the code from this article all over the internet but no one ever bothered to give you credit.  Adding credit for this solution.